# Passport-local with username only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport-local

I am building my first game and want the user to sign up with just a username.  Right now it is setup with username and password.  Can I get it to work with username only?  I am using node.js, express, mongo, and passport-local.

APP.js file

```js
//SETUP
var express     = require("express"),
    app         = express(),
    bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose    = require("mongoose"),
    flash       = require("connect-flash"),
    passport    = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose = ("passport-local-mongoose"),
    Game        = require("./models/game"),
    Story       = require("./models/story"),
    User        = require("./models/user"),
    seedDB      = require("./seeds")

//Requiring Routes
var gameRoutes  = require("./routes/game"),
    storyRoutes = require("./routes/story"),
    indexRoutes  = require("./routes/index")

//CONFIG
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(flash());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/storymash1", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true});


//PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "removed for posting",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use(gameRoutes);
app.use(storyRoutes);
```

USER.JS file

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Why don't you want the password?

Comment: I don't want a password because this is just a simple game where you just need to enter a Player name.  After the game is over, all the entries will be deleted from the database.  If you play again, you would reenter a Player name.  So, I am assuming that since no data needs protected or saved, that there is no need for a password.  And I'm trying to reduce the number of things a player has to do start a game.

Comment: Then you don't even need passport

Comment: Often the simplest solutions are the best!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. So, did you solve it?

Comment: Well, no. I re-did it without using passport and the User was just another mongoose model.  Although the code worked, I realized that I lost the ability to control the User.  So I put it back.  Since I am still a newbie, someone suggested to just get my app to work and usable - and then go back and fix the parts I don't like.

Comment: That's actually true. Remember to close this issue iif nothing else is required

Comment: did you ever tried [Passport Unique Token Strategy](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-unique-token/) ?